# Page loading time metrics in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am currently using GA4 to monitor the performance of my Vue application. Specifically, I am interested in tracking the page loading time metrics.

Currently, I am using gtag.js to collect this data and send it to GA4. However, I am wondering if there are any other methods to track page loading time that I should be aware of.

Moreover, I would like to know if it's possible to obtain the average values of page loading time metrics through exploration in GA4, or if I can only view each page's performance individually.

I have collected in every page the time to render and send it with gtag:

event(('page_load'), {
page_title: this.$options.name,
time_to_render: timeToRender,
non_interaction: true,
value: timeToRender
})

I have the data in google analytics, what I want is to visualize it, and to be able to get averages of the loading times of each page.